# urllib в python не возвращает none

Tags: python-3.x, парсер

В учебнике Митчелла по скрапингу на Python 3 написано, что urlopen от несуществующего url возвращает None. Однако, у меня вылетает длинная борода с трекингом ошибки. Как сделать чтобы возвращалось None?

upd/

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
html = urlopen("http://www.google7.ru")
```

выдает ошибку

```
gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1317                 h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
-> 1318                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1319             except OSError as err: # timeout error

D:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1238         """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1239         self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1240 

D:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
   1284             body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1285         self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1286 

D:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1233             raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1234         self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
   1235 

D:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in _send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
   1025         del self._buffer[:]
-> 1026         self.send(msg)
   1027 

D:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in send(self, data)
    963             if self.auto_open:
--> 964                 self.connect()
    965             else:

D:\Anaconda3\lib\http\client.py in connect(self)
    935         self.sock = self._create_connection(
--> 936             (self.host,self.port), self.timeout, self.source_address)
    937         self.sock.setsockopt(socket.IPPROTO_TCP, socket.TCP_NODELAY, 1)

D:\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in create_connection(address, timeout, source_address)
    703     err = None
--> 704     for res in getaddrinfo(host, port, 0, SOCK_STREAM):
    705         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

D:\Anaconda3\lib\socket.py in getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags)
    744     addrlist = []
--> 745     for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
    746         af, socktype, proto, canonname, sa = res

gaierror: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

URLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-aa56e6564ad2> in <module>()
      1 from urllib.request import urlopen
      2 
----> 3 html = urlopen("http://www.google7.ru")

D:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in urlopen(url, data, timeout, cafile, capath, cadefault, context)
    221     else:
    222         opener = _opener
--> 223     return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
    224 
    225 def install_opener(opener):

D:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in open(self, fullurl, data, timeout)
    524             req = meth(req)
    525 
--> 526         response = self._open(req, data)
    527 
    528         # post-process response

D:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _open(self, req, data)
    542         protocol = req.type
    543         result = self._call_chain(self.handle_open, protocol, protocol +
--> 544                                   '_open', req)
    545         if result:
    546             return result

D:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in _call_chain(self, chain, kind, meth_name, *args)
    502         for handler in handlers:
    503             func = getattr(handler, meth_name)
--> 504             result = func(*args)
    505             if result is not None:
    506                 return result

D:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in http_open(self, req)
   1344 
   1345     def http_open(self, req):
-> 1346         return self.do_open(http.client.HTTPConnection, req)
   1347 
   1348     http_request = AbstractHTTPHandler.do_request_

D:\Anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py in do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
   1318                           encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
   1319             except OSError as err: # timeout error
-> 1320                 raise URLError(err)
   1321             r = h.getresponse()
   1322         except:

URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

Comment: добавьте *минимальный* пример, который к ошибке приводит и саму ошибку. Какой конкретно вызов должен None по-вашему возвращать?

Comment: Обновил пост. Функция должна вернуть None

Comment: выбросите книгу, если она говорит, что  `urlopen()`  None  возвращает вместо выброса URLError исключения.

Comment: Понял.  Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как минимум [`urlopen()` функция](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.request.html) всегда возвращает объект, который как context manager можно использовать:

> This function always returns an object which can work as a context manager

В случае ошибок эта функция может выбросить исключения такие как (для неизвестного домена):

```
URLError: <urlopen error [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed>
```

`urlopen()` может вернуть `None`, если нет соответствующих обработчиков:

> Note that None may be returned if no handler handles the request

Этого не может произойти так как глобальный `OpenerDirector` использует `UnknownHandler` по умолчанию:

```
>>> from urllib.request import urlopen
>>> urlopen('unknown://')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 163, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 466, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 484, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 444, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/urllib/request.py", line 1324, in unknown_open
    raise URLError('unknown url type: %s' % type)
urllib.error.URLError: <urlopen error unknown url type: unknown>
```